# Table Name from parameter in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure. Here's a short version of my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE foobar
    @table_name nvarchar(20),
    @Work_Status nvarchar(20)
AS
BEGIN   
    update @table_name  -- /// How Do I do this? ///
    set work_status = @Work_Status
END
```

How can I define the table name via a parameter?

Comment: Is all that code necessary to demonstrate your problem? No, it is not.

Comment: Using User-defined Table Type Pass the values into that Stored proc as parameter

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I changed your title to be more in line with what you're asking (hopefully). I also simplified your code example to only show the pertinent sections. This practice is a great way to solve a problem before you post a question. As you simplify, it's easier to see some mistakes. With that being said, if you are seeing an error of some kind, please add it to your post. ALSO, if my edits do not properly showcase your issue, please edit to make sure it's correct. GL;HF

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a dynamic query:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @ParamDefinition nvarchar(500)
SET @ParamDefinition = N'@Work_Status nvarchar(20), @day_no nvarchar(10), @day_month nvarchar(10), @day_years nvarchar(10)';

--...CURSOR declaration
--... BEGIN
SELECT @SQL = 
 N'update [SKTH_ENSUSER].[dbo].' + @tbl_name + '
                set t_work_status = @Work_Status
                where t_day_no = @day_no and t_month_no = @day_month and t_year_no = @day_years'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, @ParamDefinition, @Work_Status = @Work_Status, @day_no = @day_no, @day_month = @day_month, @day_years = @day_years
--...
--       FETCH NEXT FROM ENS_cursor
```

Updated: @SQL must be NVARCHAR

Comment: Procedure sp_executesql, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.